# What is the difference between "io sto bene" & "io sono bene"?

Tags: verbs, grammar, difference

What is the difference between "io sto bene" &
"io sono bene" (or maybe just "sono bene")?
And should a beginner like me start with saying "sono" for "I am" in my sentences, i.e., when making up my own rather than using standard pre-written sentences?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE! _Io sono bene_ is simply not correct.

Comment: “should a beginner like me start with saying Sono for I am in my sentences”: I am confused: if you wanto to say “I am” in Italian, of course you say _Sono_. What do you mean?

Comment: Hank, I got the impression that you are trying to translate word-by-word from English sentences like "I am good". If that's what you're trying to do, that doesn't work at all and you'll end up mostly with incorrect or meaningless sentences.

Comment: @Hank: The problem is that, to say "I am", in some situations you have to say "sono" (for instance, "sono inglese", "sono alto" or "sono Maria"), but in other ones you must use "sto" (for instance, "sto bene").

Comment: If you want to literally translate "I am good " (verb + adjective), you would say "Io sono buono" (buono= good adjective, bene = good adverb), but for the translation of "How are you?" "I am fine" this doesn't work (Note  also that the question it's "Come stai?" and not "Come sei?")

Comment: You don't even say I am good in English. It have to be I am well.

Comment: I was asking about sentences like "I am creative". I could say Sono creativo and Sto creativo. How do I know which one is correct?

Comment: @Hank "Sono creativo" is correct. "Sto creativo" is wrong.

Comment: "Io sono bene" would confuse interlocutor, he/she'll end up parsing as "My name is Bene", which is clearly wrong. Literal translation is not good for these languages, both ways.

Answer (score 4):

The form “io sono bene” is simply ungrammatical, because *bene* is an adverb that cannot be used as a predicate.

To the contrary, *stare* is an intransitive verb, that can be accompanied by an adverb.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that, the second sentence is just wrong.